# Maximum file upload limit in php.ini have no effect on wordpress

Tags: php

I have changed the upload limits in php.ini

> sudo sublime-text /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

upload limit, post limit and something else, I restarted apache2

the phpinfo shows me both upload and post limit as 100M for master and local value inside the index file where I have setup wordpress multisite.

So my question is why the hell is WordPress still show me

> Maximum size: 1.46484375MB

I know there are 3 ways to do this with php.ini, .htaccess and inside a php file. But isn't it supposed to take effect when I change it in the very root level? In other words I don't want to set this for every site I setup in my server. I want to set this ip globally once and for all. What is maybe overwriting this?

I read on some wordpress setting in "options", I cant find anything to change under "settings". No "options" menu is there under my wp-admin.

**Got it, the thing was that I had to setup this for all subsites on the root multisite admin. The option is only available there.**

Comment: @Wayne'sWorld I'm glade that you find the solution. Please, create a new answer to tell us how did you resolved the problem. That is how the site work. Is more useful than show it into the question. Thanks!

Comment: **"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 25 minutes. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."** I can't thats the only reason I did not. And I am actually surprised the not some mod already edited this out. This is what I have seen a lot on SO sites, triggerhappy mods who enforce crappy rules without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

While the php.ini settings obviously do matter, WordPress multisite has its own settings for this as well, in the /wp-admin/network/settings.php area. It can limit by individual files and by total size of all files (a "quota" type setting).